# ESXI Won't Start VM - Failed to create swap file

Tags: linux, vmware, esxi

I have an ESXI system that I just updated to the latest release of 6.7. I shut down all of the VM's and put the host into Maintenance Mode, performed the update, and rebooted the host.

After the host came back online, I exited Maintenance Mode and started the VM's. Most of them started without issue, except for 1. I get an error when I try to start it:

```
Failed to create swap file '/vmfs/volumes/57d4c5bb-c710c8b2-e67a-9c8e991650fc/Debian - DNS 2/Debian - DNS 2-30afde53.vswp' : Not found
```

I connected to the host via SSH and found that the file is indeed not there. I then tried to use `touch` with the filename, but it threw an error. I then tried `touch` with other file names and did not receive any errors; the error only happens when I put in the exact name found in the above error.

```
$ touch "Debian - DNS 2-30afde53.vswp"
touch: Debian - DNS 2-30afde53.vswp: No such file or directory
```

I then checked the `vmware.log` file just to see if it gave any other hints, but continues to confirm that the failure is specific in creating this file:

```
2022-09-06T22:59:06.803Z| vmx| I125: CreateVM: Swap: generating normal swap file name.
2022-09-06T22:59:06.804Z| vmx| I125: FTCpt: (0 unk) vmk overheads: 0 pages (0 MB)
2022-09-06T22:59:06.804Z| vmx| I125: Swap file path: '/vmfs/volumes/57d4c5bb-c710c8b2-e67a-9c8e991650fc/Debian - DNS 2/Debian - DNS 2-30afde53.vswp'
2022-09-06T22:59:06.804Z| vmx| I125: Disk_GetDigestDiskCount: numDigestDisks = 0
2022-09-06T22:59:06.806Z| vmx| I125: Msg_Post: Error
2022-09-06T22:59:06.806Z| vmx| I125: [vob.fssvec.GetObject.fs.failed] File system specific implementation of GetObject[fs] failed
2022-09-06T22:59:06.806Z| vmx| I125: [vob.fssvec.GetObject.fs.failed] File system specific implementation of GetObject[fs] failed
2022-09-06T22:59:06.806Z| vmx| I125: [vob.swap.poweron.createfailure.status] Failed to create swap file '/vmfs/volumes/57d4c5bb-c710c8b2-e67a-9c8e991650fc/Debian - DNS 2/Debian - DNS 2-30afde53.vswp' : Not found
2022-09-06T22:59:06.806Z| vmx| I125: [msg.vmmonVMK.creatVMFailed] Could not power on virtual machine: Not found.
2022-09-06T22:59:06.806Z| vmx| I125: [msg.monitorLoop.createVMFailed.vmk] Failed to power on VM.
```

Why can I not create *this* file? I can create *any other file* on this disk. The disk is not out of space (it has ~32GB free). I haven't experienced other errors relating to the disk that I can identify.

Is there some tricks I can try to get this file created? It seems that the filesystem itself is not happy with this filename, but *only* this filename.

Comment: [This](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/ESXi-Discussions/Could-not-start-VMX-msg-vmk-status-VMK-NOT-FOUND/m-p/374627) suggests the .vmx file is corrupt.  Have you ruled this possibility out?

Comment: I'm not seeing the error described in that thread before the vswp file error. I can also cat the vmx file without issue and it doesn't outwardly look wrong. I'm tempted to think there exists some filesystem errors, but I can't seem to locate a mechanism to verify the filesystem (such as using fsck).

Comment: "Failed to create swap file '/vmfs/volumes/528532f6-ae5b9e36-bd62-7c050710dfee/xxx/vmx-xxx-276554991-1.vswp' : Not found", matches exactly, to the message you have received.  [Have you tried the resolution of recreating the .vmx file?](https://techhead.co/vmware-esx-how-to-easily-recreate-a-missing-or-corrupt-vmx-file/).

Comment: You are correct, except for the fact that I'm not getting the error `Could not start VMX: msg.vmk.status.VMK_NOT_FOUND`. I'm starting to believe the cause is filesystem corruption. Using `ls -la`, shows no file, but an `echo *` shows that the file _does_ exist, implying that the filesystem is somehow preventing the file from being removed or modified.